# Understanding ability to use AndroidX in old Apps

Tags: android, xamarin

I would like to use AndroidX if I can (instead of the support library). I read that it is backwards compatible, and people have been using it with API 21. Due to some limitations with one of our vendors... our app is built to only work on Android SDK 5, API 21. When I search for AndroidX packages in the Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio.. the Dependencies listed are MonoAndroid.Version=v9.0. Does this mean I cannot migrate to AndroidX for my project?

Comment: If your question is about Xamarin, you should consider tagging the question for that.

Comment: I *am* using Xamarin, but am curious, is the answer to this question different if I am not?

Comment: Well, standard Java/Kotlin does not have Nuget and does not have MonoAndroid.Version. Your concerns seem to stem from those things.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidX can work on API 21. MonoAndroid.Version=v9.0 is not indication of the API level, this is Microsoft's version number that has nothing to do with Google SDK version numbers.

So yes, you can migrate, I have migrated one project that targets API 21.